# Best approach to download Images in Android application

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, backgroundworker

I have an Android application which a Recycle View with each row having two images. At present, when I download all the data for the adapter (including images) in a background thread.

- Data is stored in database which has few columns. Entire data in table is fetched at once using ORM in AsyncTask.
- This data has two columns which contain image URLs. Now another AsyncTask is run to download all images (two per row).
- Once complete, data is set into recycle view adapter.

This approach seems slow especially when it comes to downloading all images.

I am instead planning to create a custom Image View where each view will download image independently in background using AsyncTask.

But I am afraid this may lead to Thread Bloat. Is there a better way ?

Comment: In getView start one thread  for every image to download it or grab from cache. When done and view is still in view use runOnUiThread to put the bitmap in its imageview. Or use setImageUri. Please do not ask for a 'best' approach.

Comment: This is similar to what I already suggested. It difference is that you suggested to do in a view, I suggested to do in a ImageView. But the question is this will lead to `2 Threads per row x (say) 100 rows = 200 threads`. Those are too many threads, any way to minimize number of threads which run simultaneously ?

Comment: I did not suggest to do it in a view but in getView().

Comment: How many rows are visible at once? 10? Then you have 20 threads. That is nothing. The total number of rows in your adapter is irrelevant if getView() is used. All is then done just in time.

Comment: @blackapps that's a good idea. But what do you mean by `getView(..)` I am setting values on UI components in `onBindViewHolder(..)`

Comment: Oh sorry. Old school using ListView. You are using RecycleView. Thats ok and the same.